# Format output for similar value in R

Tags: html, r, shiny, dplyr, r-markdown

I am looking to print/format output using `cat` or `sprintf` in `R` based on `id`:

INPUT:

```
a <- "1<--A ,1<--B ,1<--C ,1<--D"
b <- "A-->1 ,A-->2 ,A-->3 ,A-->4 ,A-->5 ,A-->6 ,B-->1 ,B-->2,C-->1,C-->3"
```

Expected Output:

```
1 <-- A
      A --> 1
      A --> 2
      A --> 3
      A --> 4
      A --> 5
      A --> 6
1 <-- B
      B --> 1
      B --> 2
1 <-- C
      C --> 1
      C --> 3
1 <-- D
```

Any help will be really appreciated. 
I want to show this output on `console` as well as in `html` formatting.

**Note: The values can have all letters and can have all numbers, Also, we have input with one char as well.

**UPDATES:**
e.g:

```
a <- "1111<--AA1 ,1111<--112 ,1111<--C1 ,1111<--DD"
b <- "AA1-->11 ,AA1-->222 ,AA1-->3 ,AA1-->4 ,AA1-->5 ,AA1-->6 ,112-->1 ,112-->2,C1-->1,C1-->3"


1111 <--  AA1
          AA1 --> 1
          AA1 --> 2
          AA1 --> 3
          AA1 --> 4
          AA1 --> 5
          AA1 --> 6
1111 <-- 112
         112 --> 1
         112 --> 2
1111 <-- C1
         C1 --> 1
         C1 --> 3
1111 <-- DD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something quick and dirty broken down into small steps (for R console):

```
library(stringr)
ab <- paste(a, b, sep = ",")
ab_split <- strsplit(ab, " *,")[[1]]
ab_split_ordered <- ab_split[order(str_extract(ab_split, "[A-Z]"), str_extract(ab_split, "[0-9]"))]
ab_split_ordered_spaced <- ifelse(grepl(">", ab_split_ordered), paste0("    ", ab_split_ordered), ab_split_ordered)
cat(ab_split_ordered_spaced, sep = "\n")

1<--A
    A-->1
    A-->2
    A-->3
    A-->4
    A-->5
    A-->6
1<--B
    B-->1
    B-->2
1<--C
    C-->1
    C-->3
1<--D
```

Data

```
a <- "1<--A ,1<--B ,1<--C ,1<--D"
b <- "A-->1 ,A-->2 ,A-->3 ,A-->4 ,A-->5 ,A-->6 ,B-->1 ,B-->2,C-->1,C-->3"
```

---

Updated example:

```
library(stringr)
ab <- paste(a, b, sep = ",")
ab_split <- strsplit(ab, " *,")[[1]]

ids <- str_extract(ab_split, "^[^<-]+(?=-)|(?<=-)[^>-]+$")
values <- str_extract(ab_split, "^[^<-]+(?=<)|(?<=>)[^>-]+$")

ab_split_ordered <- ab_split[order(ids, values)]
ab_split_ordered_spaced <- ifelse(grepl(">", ab_split_ordered), paste0(strrep(" ", max(nchar(values)) + 3), ab_split_ordered), ab_split_ordered)
cat(ab_split_ordered_spaced, sep = "\n")

       112-->1
1111<--112
       112-->2
       AA1-->11
1111<--AA1
       AA1-->222
       AA1-->3
       AA1-->4
       AA1-->5
       AA1-->6
       C1-->1
1111<--C1
       C1-->3
1111<--DD
```

Data:

```
a <- "1111<--AA1 ,1111<--112 ,1111<--C1 ,1111<--DD"
b <- "AA1-->11 ,AA1-->222 ,AA1-->3 ,AA1-->4 ,AA1-->5 ,AA1-->6 ,112-->1 ,112-->2,C1-->1,C1-->3"
```

Comment: I liked the approach, but what if we have numeric values on both side. for e.g: 12 --> 1, 15-->4 etc.

Comment: @RushabhPatel Could be adapted.. but but what if id is more than one char... etc. Better define more clearly what is the possible the input.

Comment: @RushabhPatel I have updated the example... I guess there will be more details to implement but you should be able to tinker with the steps to get it as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R approach.

```
c <- c(a,b)
d <- unlist(sapply(c,function(x){strsplit(x," ?,")}))

Direction <- gsub(".*([<>]).*","\\1",d)
Number <-  as.numeric(gsub(".*([0-9]).*","\\1",d))
Letter <-  gsub(".*([A-Z]).*","\\1",d)

data <- data.frame(Letter,Direction,Number)
data <- data[with(data, order(Letter,Direction)),]
result <- apply(data,1,function(x){
  ifelse(x["Direction"] == "<", 
         paste0(x["Number"]," ",x["Direction"],"-- ",x["Letter"],"      "),
         paste0("      ",x["Letter"]," --",x["Direction"]," ",x["Number"]))
  })
cat(result,sep="\n")
1 <-- A      
      A --> 1
      A --> 2
      A --> 3
      A --> 4
      A --> 5
      A --> 6
1 <-- B      
      B --> 1
      B --> 2
1 <-- C      
      C --> 1
      C --> 3
1 <-- D
```